# How to test if Geoloqi push notifications are working or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, location, push-notification

For normal push notifications, when something new is added to a site, a push notification is sent to the device.
So if I want to test if push notifications work how do I do that?

I tried creating triggers and Geonotes on the console with the present location I receive on my iPhone. And then tried running the triggers hoping to receive a push notification, but unfortunately I am not getting any push notification.

What am I doing wrong?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [message/send](https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/message/send) method to test sending a message directly to a device.

The simplest way is to log in to your own Geoloqi account from within your app, and then use the [API console](https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/console?method=message/send) to send a message to your device. You can of course also send messages to other accounts, just take a look at the doc page for message/send.

Comment: I managed to send a message with the access token I received , but even though it says result ok, I haven't received any push notification in my app , why is that so?